# Node red error in Json parsing function- Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

Tags: json, node-red

I have an error when trying to parse a value from JSON file.

Below the function:

```
var dt = new Date(Math.round(+new Date()));
var dt_full = (dt.getFullYear().toString() + '-' + (dt.getMonth()+1).toString() + '-' + dt.getDate().toString() + '-' + dt.getHours().toString() + '-' + dt.getMinutes().toString() + '-' + dt.getSeconds().toString())
var p = JSON.parse(msg.payload);
var C1 = p.C1;
msg.topic = "INSERT INTO mytable (id,date,index) VALUES (NULL, '"+dt_full+"', '"+C1+"')";
return msg;
```

I get following error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token E in JSON at position 0

Following json file:

```json
{
    "product": "product name",
    "status": "Success",
    "C1": 1,
    "C2": 1,
    "C3": 1,
    "C4": 0,
    "C5": 0,
    "C6": 0,
    "C7": 0,
    "C8": 0,
    "C9": 0,
    "C10": 0,
    "C11": 0,
    "C12": 0,
    "C13": 0,
    "C14": 0,
    "C15": 0,
    "C16": 0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, there is no need to run `JSON.parse(msg.payload)` in the function node, you should just include a JSON node before the function node and it will parse the string in `msg.payload` to an object.

Secondly, For that error the `msg.payload` is not the JSON string you think it is. You should attach a Debug node to the output of the node before the function node to see exactly what the input actually is.

As it is that is all we can actually say from the information in the question.